# malformed policy / self reference

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kms

I was trying to provision AWS kms key using terraform, added the code which I am using. In this kms resource I need to add a AWS kinesis firehose role to access the kms key. For that in the code I added kms key as hardcorded (after provisioning). To add this role as part of the terraform apply I tried the below options

1. Used `*` in  the `Resource` field `key/*` and got the error "malformed policy document exception"
2. Used `aws_kms_key.key.arn` Configuration for `aws_kms_key.key` may not refer to itself

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "key" {
  description             = var.description
  key_usage               = var.key_usage
  is_enabled              = true
  policy                  = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Id      = "key-default-1",
    Statement = [
       {
          Sid       = "Enable IAM User Permissions",
          Effect    = "Allow",
          Principal = { AWS = "*" },
          Action = [
            "kms:Create*",
            ..............
            "kms:CancelKeyDeletion",
          ],
          Resource = "*",
       },
       {
          "Sid": "Allow firehose role",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
             "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:role/${var.somerole}"
            },
             "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
             ],
             "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:eu-central-1:${local.account_id}:key/111-111-111"
       },
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Comment: If you want to use an implicit reference, I would probably go for this resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kms_key_policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I would prefer using a separate resource for the key instead of adding the policy to the resource used for key creation. Here is what the code would look like if you were to decide to use that approach:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "kms" {
  description             = var.description
  key_usage               = var.key_usage
  is_enabled              = true
}

resource "aws_kms_key_policy" "kms_key" {
  key_id   = aws_kms_key.kms.key_id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Id      = "kms-key-policy",
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
    { 
      Sid    = "Allow administration of the key",
      Effect = "Allow",
      Principal = {
        "AWS" = "arn:aws:iam::<your account id>:root"
    },
      Action = [
        "kms:Create*",
        "kms:Describe*",
        "kms:Enable*",
        "kms:List*",
        "kms:Put*",
        "kms:Update*",
        "kms:Revoke*",
        "kms:Disable*",
        "kms:Get*",
        "kms:Delete*",
        "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
        "kms:CancelKeyDelEetion"
       ],
       Resource = "*"
      }
      {
        Sid       = "Enable IAM User Permissions",
        Effect    = "Allow",
        Principal = { AWS = "*" },
        Action = [
          "kms:Create*",
          ..............
          "kms:CancelKeyDeletion",
        ],
        Resource = "*",
      },
        Sid = "Allow firehose role",
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
            AWS = "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:role/${var.somerole}"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        Resource = [aws_kms_key.kms.arn]
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Additionally, you could use the `aws_iam_policy_document` data source to avoid some of the pitfalls of creating the policy inline. That part could then be done like the following:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "kms_key_policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = "Allow administration of the key"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        "arn:aws:iam::<your account id>:root"
      ]
    }
    actions = [
      "kms:Create*",
      "kms:Describe*",
      "kms:Enable*",
      "kms:List*",
      "kms:Put*",
      "kms:Update*",
      "kms:Revoke*",
      "kms:Disable*",
      "kms:Get*",
      "kms:Delete*",
      "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
      "kms:CancelKeyDelEetion"
    ]
    resources = [
      "*"
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "Enable IAM User Permissions"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
    actions = [
      "kms:Create*",
      "kms:CancelKeyDeletion",
      # add whatever is missing from the actions
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "Allow firehose role"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:role/${var.somerole}"
      ]
    }
    actions = [
      "kms:Encrypt",
      "kms:Decrypt",
      "kms:ReEncrypt*",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
      "kms:DescribeKey"
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_kms_key.kms_key.arn
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "kms" {
  description             = var.description
  key_usage               = var.key_usage
  is_enabled              = true
}

resource "aws_kms_key_policy" "kms_key" {
  key_id = aws_kms_key.kms.key_id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.kms_key_policy.json
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marko, But am getting Error: attaching KMS Key policy (aabbcc): updating policy: MalformedPolicyDocumentException: The new key policy will not allow you to update the key policy in the future.

Comment: Ah, ok, I will add the missing part.

Comment: @Wonderhost updated, just make sure to replace `<your account id>` with the account ID you are running the apply in.